# finding matrix represention for linear transformation for field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

need some clarification.

given an extension field K over F with F-linear transformation,

for $\alpha \in K$,  $f_\alpha(k) = \alpha \cdot k$ i.e. multiplication on the left.

I need to find the matrix $A$ such that  it can be used to give the minimal polynomial.

In this $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$ so using basis $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ for K as a vector space over F

and multiplication on the left  of some $k \in K$ such that $k = 1x+\sqrt[3]{2}y+\sqrt[3]{4}z$ get $\sqrt[3]{2}k = \sqrt[3]{2}(1x+\sqrt[3]{2}y+\sqrt[3]{4}z) = \sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{4}y +2z$

heres my issue, and its probably really clear but its been a while since linear algebra.

Why does this give $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0&2\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]$  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $E=K(\alpha)$, $e_1=1,e_2=\alpha,e_3=\alpha^2$, $e=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. Then $E$ is a vector space over $K$ and $e$ it's basis. Let $f=f_\alpha$, then $f:E\to E$ - linear operator on the $E$. 
$$
f(e_1)=\alpha\cdot 1=e_2=0e_1+1e_2+0e_3,
$$
$$
f(e_2)=\alpha^2=e_3=0e_1+0e_2+1e_3,
$$
$$
f(e_3)=\alpha^3=2=2e_1=2e_1+0e_2+0e_3,
$$
hence, matrix of $f$ in the basis $e$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$